# Deducing template return type based on operator?: result

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, c++14

Consider this code:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto max(T1 t1, T2 t2) -> decltype(true?t1:t2)
{
  return t2 < t1 ? t1 : t2;
}
```

When calling this function with `::max(5, 7.2)` I'm expecting the returned type to be `int` as `decltype(t1)` is in this case `int`.

Why is the deduced return type `double` in the above code when using `operator?:` inside the decltype?

If I do `-> decltype(t1)` I get the expected return type `int`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the result type of [conditional operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other#Conditional_operator) is determined at compile-time. It won't return different types based on the condition but would return the common type of the operands as the result.

> 6.2) If both E2 and E3 have arithmetic or enumeration type: the [*usual arithmetic conversions*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#conversions) are applied to bring them to common type, and that type is the result.

And for this case, i.e. one operand is `int` and another is `double`, the result type will be `double`.

> - Otherwise, if either operand is double, the other operand is converted to double

BTW: You can use [`std::common_type`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type) (since C++11) to get the common type.